# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: ((react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState < Boolean) > false) is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, arrays, next.js

`const [ productShow, setProductShow ] = useState<Boolean>(false);`

I am using next js 13 version

I got this error and please helpme to fix this

**Unhandled Runtime Error**

**TypeError: ((react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState < Boolean) > false) is not iterable**

Comment: Can we see the whole file and a full error stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Did you import useState properly? it should look like this `import { useState } from 'react'`, but it's sometimes being imported without the "{}" brackets

Comment: yes I have imported `import { Fragment, useState } from "react";`